# For Loop to do repetitive checking of variables for me

Tags: xcode, loops, for-loop, task

```
NSArray *test = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"22", @"3", @"22", @"5", @"1", @"0", @"2", nil];

NSArray *test2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"21", @"2", @"20", @"5", @"1", @"9", @"2", nil];

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

   if ([test objectAtIndex:i] == [test2 objectAtIndex:i]); {

testVariable = testVariable + 1; 
    }

}    

NSLog(@"%i", testVariable);
```

I tried the above code to test comparison of variables but it returns 7 when it should return 3. Do I need to somehow retrieve and store each array object in a local variable and compare thos against each other? Or can I do something more direct like what I tried above.
Arrays are very interesting. :)

UPDATE:

Got it to work with NSInteger.. :)
Guess I was comparing objects and not the actual integer numbers before..

Comment: Did you check the semicolon after the if-statement.
Maybe this one also caused some trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can use preprocesor

```
#define variable(name,number) {name##number}
```

and later in the loop

```
for (int a = 1; a <= 53; a++) {    
    if ((variable(taken,a) == 2) && (variable(hidden,a) == 2)) {
        //Do something
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is not to use different variables. Use a collection or an array instead. Then you could have:

```
if (taken[a] == 2 && hidden[a] == 2) {
    ...
}
```

Think of using an array whenever you find yourself putting numeric suffixes on variables of the same type and prefix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not used to arrays and have some difficulty understanding them at the moment. Could you quickly demonstrate the steps needed before the lines you wrote, to be able to use an array in this case? Is there no way besides the array way to do this?

Comment: arrays would be the most efficient way to do it, here is a nice tutorial:      http://www.idleloop.com/tutorials/introC/introC-10.php

Comment: @ArthDent: I'm not an Objective C programmer (I assume that's what you're using), and I could easily introduce more confusion by giving you the wrong advice. I would *strongly* advise you to get a book on Objective C. It's very important to understand the basics of the language you're using... and learning piecemeal via Stack Overflow isn't really a great idea IMO. It's good for specific topics you're having trouble with, but not for initial learning.